# Gnome Installation Issue Debian

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, nautilus

With the command

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core -f
```

I got

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
          gnome-core : Depends: nautilus (>= 3.22) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: gnome-sushi (>= 3.20) but it is not going to be installed
          E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So i tried:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus -f
```

I got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
        nautilus : Depends: libnautilus-extension1a (= 3.22.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: gnome-sushi but it is not going to be installed
        E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-sush -f
```

I got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
        gnome-sushi : Depends: nautilus (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
        E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Finally I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libnautilus-extension1a -f
```

And I obtained:

```
libnautilus-extension1a is already the newest version (1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9).
```

I tried also to clean using (*sudo* is missing because i was root):

```
apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

**source.list**

> deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
>
> deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main
>
> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
>
> deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main

**OS**

> 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1kali1 (2017-05-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Could you add your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @EsaJokinen sorry, I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using Debian, but [Kali](https://www.kali.org/about-us/). Then, for some reason, you are having this package [`libnautilus-extension1a 1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1`](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/armhf/libnautilus-extension1a/1:3.14.2-0ubuntu9.1) from Ubuntu Vivid, while Kali-rolling (& Stretch) has `3.22.3-1`.

You could use

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --force-hold libnautilus-extension1a
```

to remove it. From `man dpkg`:

> **hold** A package marked to be on hold is not handled by dpkg, unless forced
>   to do that with option `--force-hold`.
>
> **reinst-required** A package marked reinst-required
>   is broken and requires reinstallation. These packages cannot be
>   removed, unless forced with option `--force-remove-reinstreq`.

Then you can `sudo apt-get update` and try to reinstall from your normal apt sources.

Comment: You are right i had to remote it manually first, and after update and upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

You have held broken packages because you have a mixed `sources.list` : debian wheezy , ubuntu trusty , precise and kali rolling

Edit your `sources.list` , only keep the following line:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Update your package

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
```

Then install gnome desktop:

```
apt-get install gnome-core kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base
```

Comment: The package `libnautilus-extension1a` wasn't from any of the sources. The launcpad.net `trusty/precise` only contained Java for Ubuntu, and `3.12.2-0ubuntu9.1` is from Vivid. I suppose it's manually installed from a `.deb` package. Kali is based on Debian testing: I think it could actually get security updates from debian-security `stretch/updates`, but not from the `wheezy/updates` in current setting.

Comment: [Kali sources.list Repositories](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) documentation is in line with this answer: "The single most common causes of a broken Kali Linux installation are following unofficial advice, and particularly arbitrarily populating the system’s `sources.list` file with unofficial repositories. - - **Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.**"